# How do I make a Perl Tk::Frame look like a LCD?

Tags: linux, perl, fonts, perl-module

I want a [Tk::Frame](http://p3rl.org/Tk%3a%3aFrame) to look like a LCD. Inside the frame I have a [Tk::Label](http://p3rl.org/Tk%3a%3aLabel) and a [Tk::Entry](http://p3rl.org/Tk%3a%3aEntry). Does anyone know a font name or method to do this, maybe a Perl module?

Comment: Is there a seven segment display font for Linux? Or perhaps font from
another OS convertible to Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Steve Lidie's [Tk::LCD](http://search.cpan.org/~lusol/Tk-LCD-1.3/LCD.pm) to make an alarm clock, but had to hack in a few missing features.
[image]

Comment: how you did with 00, in your case ? or 0:00:00 .in cant show 00 value